# Should we downvote?

Tags: discussion

These questions have easily searchable answers.

[Which was the first animated movie in hollywood?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/which-was-first-animated-movie-in-hollywood)

[Which was first TV show with animation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/which-was-first-tv-show-with-animation)

So what should we do when these types of questions are posted. Downvotes mean they show lack of "Research", obviously they show so. But I found them also interesting and that the information should be kept in the site according to the [blog entry by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). So in these situations like these questions what should we do? Downvote, Answer or close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For searching 'first animated movie in Hollywood' that gives all different results:

1. http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_was_the_first_animated_film_made_in_Hollywood
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animated_feature_films
3. http://movies.about.com/od/animatedmovies/a/history-animated-films.htm
4. http://www.hollywoodfilmoffice.org/history.php

Sometimes we do search on internet(i.e. Google). Then we get some links over there. Their might be different cases.

1. We can presume information is correct or incorrect.
2. We can have different resources saying all different information.

So what should person believe true information is? There should be some official resources.

Let's talk about Movie.SE. When this types of question are brought here. Then we can have broad discussions with proof. And then can understand which is correct answer or facts about movies or TV shows. If question really needs discussion or fair resources then it should brought to Movie.SE.

See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies-tv. Currently 8 questions/ day and 15 questions/day on average is a healthy beta. But that doesn't means wrong questions should be brought here. But I think question which really needs discussion should be brought here.

Comment: Be careful with that word 'discussion'  Discussion is what is to be avoided here.  While we can have more 'open-eneded' questions than most other SE's, we will still disallow and close questions that turn into outright discussion.

Comment: Yes I will. In this, discussion mean 'supposed to answers' in respective with condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is the community's decision, overall.  If you don't like the question, downvote it.  If you think it doesn't belong here at all, vote to close.

With all the [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) questions we have, these don't seem any different, just more easily answered.

Comment: If I downvote, what would be the reason(within the given options)?

Comment: That is up to you.  Typically downvotes suggest that the author need to clarify their post, do more research into their subject, or lack of understanding what the problem is.  also sometimes for low quality posts in general tha tmight not belong.